# Using a Jquery Function on multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetimepicker

I am working on a project, where at one point you have to add multiple dates. The Problem is that the Date & Time Pickers work on the first set of textboxes, won't work on any of the following, dynamically added textboxes.

Here is the whole Javascript Code(The different date & time pickers & the function to add additional textboxes):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.end').datetimepicker({
            datepicker:false,
            format:'H:i:s',
            step:5
        });
        $('.start').datetimepicker({
            datepicker:false,
            format:'H:i:s',
            step:5
        });
        $('.date').datetimepicker({
            timepicker:false,
            lang:'de',
            format:'Y-m-d',
            formatDate:'Y-m-d'
        });
        var counter = 2;

        $("#addButton").click(function () {
            if(counter>10){
                    alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
                    return false;
            }   
            var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
            newTextBoxDiv.attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv'+counter);
            newTextBoxDiv.attr("class", 'termin');

            newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Termin #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
                                       '<input type="textbox" class="date"   name="datum' + counter + '">' + 
                                       '<input type="textbox" class="start" name="start' + counter + '">' + 
                                       '<input type="textbox" class="end" name="end' + counter + '">');
            newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

            counter++;
         });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you just apply the datepicker to the dynamic elements _after_ their creation?

Comment: Yes, you must enhance the <input> boxes after they are appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you fire `$('.end').datetimepicker`, at this moment, jQuery will search for all elements with class end, and run the datepicker. when you add dynamically elements, for each element you must run the function again.

like `newTextBoxDiv.find(".end").datetimepicker();`